# Archive is refused by iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode

When I build my app it doesn't show and when it complete in build and the app says:

> [WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.2 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."]

Answer (score 1):

What the message says. You need to to set your SDK to 12.1 or higher in Xcode's project inspector. Check your target **Build Settings**.

Xcode 10 doesn't appear to give version numbers on the SDK so just delete your own setting, if it exists; to allow the default to reappear.

[image]
In the **General** tab you can have a deployment target of lower than 12.1 if needed

[image]

Comment: where is the base sdk location